# How to use response.addCookie() in a JSP page?

Tags: jsp, servlets, cookies

How can I set a cookie in a `JSP` page and read it in a `servlet`?

Also the value of the cookie has to be extracted from a var inside the script tag.

Using `document.cookie` is not helping.

I think I need to use `response.addCookie()` in the `JSP page`, but how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Maybe you should explain what you want to use the cookie for and show some code.

Comment: If you don't need to read it client-side but only server-side, then use session rather than cookies.  Cookies can be altered by the user, and intercepted by others.